# Python packaing - How is the python egg dir name like `myapp-0.2a40-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg` generated?

Tags: python, python-packaging, egg

I installed a python package `My-App` with `python setup.py install` and an egg directory `My_App-0.2a40-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg` is created under my `site-packages`.

I looked up setuptools docs and source code and some PEPs trying to figure out how the egg dir name `My_App-0.2a40-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg` is generated, but I didn't find anything relavent.

So how is the python egg dir name like `My_App-0.2a40-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg` generated?

- How does `My-App` package name in the `setup.py` get converted to `My_App` in the dir name?
- `py3.9-linux-x86_64` looks like a platform tag, but not exactly - it doesn't contain `cp39` etc. I want to know how this is generated.

Comment: Which part are you confused about, or trying to control? Or are you trying to make a cross-platform build?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Please see the edited question. No, I'm trying to write a function that get the egg dir name generated by `python setup.py install`. :)

Comment: AFAIK, it's just a template of `{package_name}-{version}-py{version}-{platform}-{arch}.egg`. `cp39` shouldn't be needed since the egg should be installable in any Python environment, not only CPython

Comment: Can you point out the code that generates this string? I want to be able to do that in my code, but I'm afraid I might sometimes get {arch} wrong. @OneCricketeer

Answer (score 1):

The doc https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/python_eggs.html points out the functions used to construct the egg dir name.

> The “name” and “version” should be escaped using the to_filename()
> function provided by pkg_resources, after first processing them with
> safe_name() and safe_version() respectively. These latter two
> functions can also be used to later “unescape” these parts of the
> filename. (For a detailed description of these transformations, please
> see the “Parsing Utilities” section of the pkg_resources manual.)
>
> The “pyver” string is the Python major version, as found in the first
> 3 characters of sys.version. “required_platform” is essentially a
> distutils get_platform() string, but with enhancements to properly
> distinguish Mac OS versions. (See the get_build_platform()
> documentation in the “Platform Utilities” section of the pkg_resources
> manual for more details.)
>
> Finally, the “ext” is either .egg or .egg-info, as appropriate for the
> egg’s format.